# How can I construct a link to a "neighbour" resource in react router v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I've got a React app using React Router v6. I've got a route matching a path with multiple path parameters, something like this:

`/event/:eventId/resource/:resourceId`

These are represented by nested routes, something like:

```
<Route path="/event/:eventId/*" element={<Event />}>
  <Route path="resource/:resourceId" element={<Resource />} />
</Route>
```

I have multiple events and multiple resources. A single resource might appear in the context of multiple events, corresponding to urls like this:

- `/event/event-1/resource/resource-1`
- `/event/event-2/resource/resource-1`

Individual resources are linked to other resources. I want to be able make links on a resource page to the other linked resources, in the context of the same event.

So on the page:

`/event/event-1/resource/resource-1`,

which renders my `Resource` component, and given that `resource-1` has links to `resource-2` and `resource-3`, I might want to make links to these urls:

- `/event/event-1/resource/resource-2`
- `/event/event-1/resource/resource-3`

But, I don't want to hard-code the paths for those links in my `Resource` component if I can avoid it.

React Router 6 allows me to create nested routes and links, so I can build up long links without having to know the full path up to that point. Does it provide a nice way to make these links without hard coding the full path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of [`generatePath`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#generatepath), and/or write your own function helpers:

```js
import { generatePath } from 'react-router-dom';

export function getResourcePath({ eventId, resourceId }) {
  return generatePath('/event/:eventId/resource/:resourceId', { eventId, resourceId });
}
```

In your components:

```js
import { getResourcePath } from '...';

...

<Link to={getResourcePath(...)}/>
```